# What unit of measure is the value returned by LeadingMarginSpan2.getLeadingMargin(boolean)?

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android, what unit of measure is using the number returned by [`LeadingMarginSpan2.getLeadingMargin()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/LeadingMarginSpan.html#getLeadingMargin(boolean))?

Is it `px` or `dip`?

Comment: It will return pixeis.

Comment: thanks, you could add this as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested by OP:

`LeadingMarginSpan2.getLeadingMargin()` will return the value in pixels (px).